# what are the downside (and upside) to calling javascript as HTML php style

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am in a JavaScript only framework, where I cant use php.
So instead of

```
<?php include ('header.php'); ?>
```

I can put the HTML into JavaScript write function and use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/header.js"> </script>
```

The page is only showing information that will only display when JavaScript is on, so I am not worried about losing people who do not have JavaScript.

Here is what I think are the pluses and minuses of trying to replicate this PHP function in JavaScript:  Am I missing something?  Big?

PLUS

- Can edit many pages from editing just one file
- Each individual html file will be smaller, so pre rendering the site will be smaller

MINUS

- HTML wrapped in JS code makes the filesize bigger
- Call extra files slows page load?
- (will not work if JavaScript turned off)

Am I missing a problem structuring pages like this?

-

Comment: *"...so pre rendering the site will be smaller"* Not necessarily. A script element blocks the rendering until the script is loaded and executed. you should make some testing

Comment: not very constructive.

Comment: if I have a site with 100 pages of 10kb each.  And I change it to 101 pages, 100 at 2kb & 1 at 15kb - site will be much smaller as a total.  By pre rendering I mean the site KB as a whole in file size, not as loaded on a browser etc.  There are various benefits of this.  Do you think that is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like I am missing something since nobody has pointed it out yet, but there is a very HUGE difference between JS and PHP: PHP is used for serverside scripting while JS works on the client side. There are very few things where this is NOT an issue.

 E.g. if you want to populate your site with information from a database, that will not be possible with JS only (Supposed that your database is configured to only accept connections from localhost, which most databases are for security reasons).

Comment: as I say I am in a framework that I cant use PHP.  So I cant use databases.  I am using arrays instead.  My question is not PHP Vs JS, its what are the blindspots using JS to call includes  php style

Comment: Ok, I think I got that correct now. But I also still believe that the comparison is somewhat flawed... The PHP 'inlclude' would add the PHP code to the HTML document and execute it before delivering the HTML document to the client. It's totally dependent on what that script does to determine how it behaves. if it just dumps massive amount of data, of course that will slow down the page load. If, on the other hand, it makes a bunch of calculations, that might even more slow down the page load. If you include a JS-Script, what slows you down is the extra request for the script.

Comment: ... So, in an attempt to answer your question: The JS-scripts are fetched by individual requests (no preprocessor bundling them with the document), so you profit from very small files. There are tools out there that shorten your JS files (short variable names etc.) once you wrote them. Also, some browsers cache your scripts (remember this when testing, it sometimes is a pain...). A very nice plus is, that you can include JS-Scripts from other pages, since the browser does not care from where to fetch them.

Comment: yes cached pages is a big plus.  I have a bunch of HTML code that is repeated on 100 pages.  I have the option of replacing this code with a JS callout.  From what you are saying the is little downside to this, & decent gains.  Thanks.

Comment: @Romiox - Not entirely correct, JavaScript [can be used on the server side](http://nodejs.org/) and [can use databases](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) although it's not very scalable compared to PHP, Java etc.

Comment: Yes, of course it can, like, there is the possibility of doing that. But from the code in the question it becomes very clear that that was not meant. Also, what would have been a good link here would be a CGI-extension that allowed your JS code serverside, but NodeJS really is an entirely different route to go. (Not that I didn't enjoy it! :) )